# Json object sort by value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a json object and i want to sort it by ascending order. My json is like

```
Object {8="Two Wheeler Dealers/Showroom", ...}
```

The key are dynamically created, next time may be changed. How I can sort this into

Comment: Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/mcuzr/

Comment: please add a valid object, and the key you like to order.

Comment: Use an array, the object(key/value pair ) is not a sorted data structure

Comment: Have a look at the following Gist: https://gist.github.com/colingourlay/82506396503c05e2bb94

Comment: please tell me in detail

Comment: *You are free to accept an answer, if it helped you and you don't have any more questions.  **:)**  Otherwise feel free to ask.*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already parsed your JSON string to a valid javascript object (i'll refer to it as `myObj`).

Then you can use something like that:

```
var keys = Object.keys(myObj),
    sortedArray = [];

keys.sort();
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    sortedArray.push( myObj[ keys[i] ] );
}
```